# IBM Worklight 6.1 Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Test the worklight 6.1 sample Integrating server-generated pages in hybrid applications. Preview Mobile Browser Simulator displays mobile web pages. But click the external webview is not display anything. Then try run as android application has error message.

```
[2014-04-12 21:31:28 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2014-04-12 21:31:28 - IncludeExternalPagesIncludeExternalPagesAndroid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

Eclipse error log

```
message:
Failed to load properties file for project 'IncludeExternalPages'
Exception Stack Trace:
An exception stack trace is not available.

Session Data:
    eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
    java.version=1.7.0_51
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=zh_TW
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/hunghui/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
    Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/hunghui/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third tab of this sample will obviously not work in the MBS because it is loading an external page using a Cordova plug-in (= native code). This will not work in a browser.

You must test it in either the Android Emulator or physical device, and there it should work.

If it also fails for you in an Android device/emulator, you must edit the question and explain the steps you've taken (= what did you do in Eclipse prior to running the app).

In addition, the log you're supplying is totally not the full log. Also provide the FULL LogCat log.

For the error you do get, which is not related to Worklight, try googling "[java.nio.BufferOverflowException](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=java.nio.BufferOverflowException&oq=java.nio.BufferOverflowException)"

Comment: Dear lean： very thanks your help, i goolge bufferoverflowexception. Found the problem is how to setting method. And cordova plug-in is really can not run on MBS.